# Which tags attract drive-by questions? Or: How do I compute, for each tag, the number of users of that tag who have ≤N total questions?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

I'm currently thinking about questions with the *[character-identification](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-identification)* tag at *[Chinese Language](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/tour)*.  I feel like a lot of the questions with this tag are "drive-by" questions, i.e., the user comes along asks e.g. "what does my tattoo say?" and never uses the site again.  I'd like to get data on this.

I didn't find the exact query on Data Explorer; the closest I found was [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/chinese/query/1454727/user-stats-on-answering-drive-by-user-questions-per-tag-and-in-a-time-period).  Changing `= 1` to `<= N` is easy enough, but I don't know how to modify it so that it lists all the site's tags, along with the number of `SingleUserQuestions` with that tag.

How do I compute, for each tag, the number of users of that tag who have ≤N total questions?

Ideally, it'd be great to get the proportion too, as well as the number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your hunch is right: [character-identification] has a lot of drive-by users asking questions. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/chinese/query/1607828/drive-by-users?maximumNumberOfQuestions=1) confirms that. Only [seal] seems 'worse' but it has significant overlap with [character-identification]. You can vary the `N` with the [query parameter](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#parameters).

[image]

The query probably times out on larger sites; writing efficient SQL has never been one of my talents.

Comment: Thanks!  I just noticed now I asked for "number of questions" rather than "number of users", but I think your query makes more sense.  I should edit the question to match the answer.